# Strange Outlook 2010 attachment auto conversion issue

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pdf, microsoft-outlook-2010, attachments

My coworker has a number of PDF attachments that come in and are sent by her through Microsoft Outlook 2010. Today her email attachments of document scans have all started to show as jpgs with a generic naming format instead of PDFs. Furthermore, all of her emails from the past have jpgs now instead of PDFs. I'd like to know what caused it and, if possible, convert everything back to PDFs. There was no loss of image quality, she just wants her old pdf formats back on the email attachments without having to download and convert everything.

Other information that might be related or helpful:

Yesterday there was some trouble opening a jpg attachment as it came from a phone and was auto rotated. I helped her fix it by saving the images off the email and rotating them with a right click. Each photo was accompanied by a blank text document. She thinks this may have caused it to convert everything but I have no idea how it would have triggered it.

New incoming emails have had no issues, the attachments are coming in as PDFs. It is simply old emails that are all .jpg now instead of .pdf

Additional information, things I thought to check because of helpful comments

This happens in Outlook /safe.
Now I've taken another look, and restarted Outlook, it appears not all the PDFs have been converted. Only the ones scanned by her sent out to the boss. I'm investigating the scanner. It should not have converted all the email attachments in her sent email and inbox folder but it can't be ignored.

Comment: Does this happen when running `Outlook /safe`? Are PDF file double-clicked in Explorer open in a PDF reader?

Comment: It still happens when running Outlook /safe. PDF files double clicked open in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Now I've taken another look, and restarted Outlook, it appears not all the PDFs have been converted. Only the ones scanned by her sent out to the boss. I'm investigating the scanner. It should not have converted all the email attachments in her sent email and inbox folder but it can't be ignored.

Comment: Also now all jpgs open in Internet Explorer when clicked in the emails.

Comment: Better re-establish the "Open with" of PDFs. Does this change anything?

Comment: The PDFs were already set for opening with Adobe Acrobat. The "open with" fixed the jpgs opening in Internet Explorer at least. My coworker is happy with that. She's wondering if her scanner ever did scan her stuff as PDFs to begin with. I'm declaring this fixed. You rock.

Comment: I have added an answer accordingly. Please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was fixed by re-establishing Adobe Acrobat as the handler for PDF,
as somehow it was replaced by Internet Explorer.

This seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually, it was just changing the Open with for jpgs. She thought the documents were always PDF because of how it viewed in Windows Photo Viewer and because when she scans to save to computer it saves as a PDF. As it turns out, her emails scan to jpg and seem to always have.